# Is it possible to multithread to execute non-void functions at the same time? (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, concurrency, parallel-processing

Suppose I have a function that log transforms a vector, multiplied by a constant, thus I defines a function that maps, given the vector, and the constant....

```
vector<double> logtransform(vector<double> &data, int constant){
    vector<double> image;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
        image.push_back(constant*log(data[i]));
    }
    return image;
}
```

Given a vector named "data", I need to apply the function "logtransform" for varying number of constants, contained in an array of doubles, but how can I use multithreading to execute that function at the same time if the function is not a void type?

Comment: What does the type have to do with anything?

Comment: First, you should at least `reserve` data.size() elements in the vector. Here it will be better to `resize` the vector, and then just assign the transformed value to each position in the vector.  This can now be parallelized (using OpenMP or actually creating a helper function that does the transformation in-place.

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing when executing this function in multiple threads?

Comment: You probably rather want to dissect your `for()` loop to be executed in parallel by multiple cores, each one responsible to calculate a particular range of the `log[data]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [std::future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) to collect results from other threads when they are ready like this:

```
std::vector<double> logtransform(std::vector<double> const& data, int constant)
{
    std::vector<double> image;
    image.reserve(data.size());

    std::transform(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::back_inserter(image),
        [constant](double d){ return constant * std::log(d); });

    return image;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> data = {0.3, 0.7, 0.9};

    // start a thread to do the transform
    // remember to pass data by reference using std::cref() (constant reference)
    auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, logtransform, std::cref(data), 5);

    // do something else in parallel
    for(auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << " " << i;
    std::cout << '\n';

    // collect results
    auto results = future.get(); // will wait if thread not finished

    for(auto d: results)
        std::cout << " " << d;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Note:** Requires `C++11`

The function [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) launches a thread to do the work and returns a [std::future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) that you can use to pick up the results later.

Comment: wow great answer. By the way, is there a necessity of having to "do something else in parallel" ? is It necessary to have that for loop printing out from 0 to 9?

Comment: @MikeChen The for loop is just an example. There is no point creating a new thread if you are not going to do other work at the same time in the current thread. That loop is an example of such work.

Answer (score 3):

Use the standard library. Begin with `std::transform` and get it working:

```
std::vector<double> image(data.size()); // allocate all elements!
std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), image.begin(),
    [](double val) { return constant*log(val); });
```

I think that's right, but I haven't tested it.

Once you have it working, parallelise it:

```
std::vector<double> image(data.size()); // allocate all elements!
std::transform(std::execution::par,
    data.begin(), data.end(), image.begin(),
    [](double val) { return constant*log(val); });
```

The only change to parallelise it is adding that new first argument, `std::execution::par`. This requires C++17.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with C++17 and never learned execution::par, but looks promising.